# Tracking Postback in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, request, buttonclick

I am having an issue with an image button being clicked, and then the on click event of that button is not being fired, part of the issue I think is that a validator on the page is firing and then suppressing the button click, but I cannot find what is causing it.
Is there any way to see the events that a request goes through?
I assume that there is something is happening before the post back occurs, as I can catch the page as it comes back to Page_Load, but I need to know what is happening before that.

Is this even possible to find out?

Answer (score 0):

is it an `ImageButton` ? If yes, set [`CauseValidation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.causesvalidation.aspx) to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get some info by enabling tracing for the page.

Before Load, you only have PreInit at the Page level, followed by Init for all Controls (bottom-up), Init for the Page, then InitComplete for the Page, then Load for the Page, then Load for all Controls (top-down).